# Voltage transfer

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-nano

I'm trying to read the battery voltage using Arduino, using a 9V battery. I keep getting the same voltage (4.99). I connected my Arduino to Matlab so I'm only using the command `voltage=readVoltage(a,'pin')`. I'm very new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

[image: thats my circuit]

Answer (score 3):

Analog inputs on the arduino will measure 5v maximum. If you want to mesure higher voltage you will have to use a voltage divisor circuit (resistors).

Comment: Also your analog input might now be dead from providing almost twice the voltage it's designed for.

Comment: Aren't you getting any Magic smoke ?

Comment: Thank you all, somehow I didnt damage the analog input, thank God. But i tried with resistors (10k) and its still measuring the same voltage...

Comment: And if you measure with a multi-meter the voltage at the Arduino input ?

Comment: @SoundoussSassi could you show/describe how you have connected the resistors (just to make sure it is a proper voltage divider)? I also wonder if it is necessary to select a proper reference (there should be an internal and external reference possible).